# Fragment that expand over another one

Tags: android, fragment

I would like to have 2 fragments visible on the same screen, but one of the two can be expanded by clicking or swiping top/bottom the expandable fragment.
I've made some research and I've found this [blog article](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) . But unfortunately is written under Xamarin code template and not clearly understandable to do in Java.

I've some ideas about how to do that by clicking but for swiping bottom/top it's a little bit more complex I think.

This image explains well what I would like to do :

[image: Image of wanted animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to use the (open source and free as in Beer) SlidingUpPanel created (and open sourced) by umano. You can clone the project from their [official git hub repository](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

> The 2.2 version of the Umano Android app features a sexy sliding up draggable panel for the currently playing article. This type of a panel is a common pattern also used in the Google Music app and the Rdio app. This is an open source implementation of this component that you are free to take advantage of in your apps. Umano Team <3 Open Source.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, i'm going to sleep, but I will try it as soon as I am wake up :). This library must be added to : http://www.androidviews.net/

Comment: Yeah, it should, but it's up to them to add I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative, more customizable I think can be found here : https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib for those who want to stick the sliding panel to TOP/LEFT/RIGHT/BOTTOM.

Hope this help to.

[Demonstration video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=162oD0XPM40)